# iTunes unable to change Artwork for Albums

Tags: itunes

With iTunes 12.7.0 and OS 10.13 I cannot change the Album Artwork. Checked permissions and its all Read & Write. The tracks of the Album are my own creation and in AIFF format. I've tried cutting and pasting, dragging of jpegs, and software select - but even though the image appears - when I select OK it reverts to previous image.
I tried deleting the image  - which was deleted, but still cannot paste my own jpeg (small 100k). Frustrated.

Answer (score 1):

try change the image format in .png 'Important: iTunesArtwork icon images should be in png format, but name them without the .png extension.' source: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1686/_index.html

Edit: Ultimately ITunes used the cover of a pdf from iBooks as a generic image, to solve this problem I found this solution that works for me:
"Choose the 'Options' tab in Album Info. The media kind would be 'Mixed'. Change it to 'Music'. Now you can see a pdf as part of the album. If you delete the pdf, you can now set your album artwork."
source: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7127569